# INSERT INTO without column names with OUTPUT INSERTED

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I would like to create a SQL statement that will copy a given record and return the inserted ID, such as:

```
INSERT INTO DF_FILES
OUTPUT INSERTED.TableID
SELECT *
FROM DF_FILES
WHERE DOC = "myFile.txt"
```

Then I attempt to capture the ID using the following:

```
Int32 t_ID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

When I run the statement via C# `SqlCommand`, I get the following error message.

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'DF_FILES' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Is there a workaround for getting the ID of a newly created record?

Thanks,
Darin

Comment: I think the query generates an error when you execute it. Try executing the query directly in SQL Server Management Studio. The error might be caused by your table having an indentity column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"INSERT INTO without column names" works only when you are inserting values for all columns in the table and in the exact same order.

In this case, since the TableID seems to have IDENTITY_INSERT turned ON which means that the value of the column in computed for each row based on the state of the identity and hence you cannot just insert a new value into it. If you list out all the columns in the DF_FILES table without the TableID  and try to insert, you might be able to work around this.

```
  INSERT INTO DF_FILES (col1, col2 , col3 ...)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.TableID
  SELECT col1, col2 , col3 ...
  FROM DF_FILES
  WHERE DOC = "myFile.txt"
```

Comment: There are 20+ columns and each table varies which I would like to run using a for each loop for each table. Is there an alternative method you could recommend?

Comment: Based on your query, you seem to be inserting entries from the DF_Files tables back into the same table. Is that your actual query or just an example query you posted?

Comment: @Bean: in that case, you need to explicitly list 19+ columns (omitting the `IDENTITY` column - that'll be filled automatically by SQL Server) in your SQL statement ....

Comment: @KnightFox: Yes, I'm making a copy of a record then I need to change the value of a given field for the newly created record.

Comment: when you insert value of a given field for the new row, and then update it later, you might run into issues with concurrency. I am guessing you are using the outputed TableID to run another update statement. Rather than that consider passing the values of the fields that need to be changed to the query itself. Your query would be
 INSERT INTO DF_FILES (col1, col2 , col3 ...)
  SELECT TOP 1 'new value' as col1, 'another value' as col2 , col3 ...
  FROM DF_FILES
  WHERE DOC = "myFile.txt" where col1 and col2 are fields you want changed